Kafka Default Partitioner is getting invoked twice, is it normal?
I am using springboot 2.7.8 with apache camel 3.20.2 , while debugging I noticed that Kafka DefaultPartitioner.partition() method is getting invoked twice.
However there is no problem I am facing with this , but is this normal behavior?

Please show your code and debug logs / stacktrace?
